# Cannot find function after loading library R

Tags: r, gdata, startswith

Im having some troubles with the `startsWith` function in R.

After an update of the library `gdata` that contains the function, this test script gives an error:

```
library(data.table)
library(gdata)

help.search("startsWith");

print(startsWith("test","t"));
```

I also tried to use `gdata::startsWith("test","t")` or `gdata:::startsWith("test","t")`
but nothing chages.

The error I get is the following:

```
Error in get(name, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : 
  oggetto "startsWith" non trovato
Calls: print -> <Anonymous> -> :: -> getExportedValue -> get
```

While the search part finds the function `startsWith`, returning this message:

```
gdata: read.xls support for 'XLS' (Excel 97-2004) files ENABLED.

gdata: read.xls support for 'XLSX' (Excel 2007+) files ENABLED.

Attaching package: ‘gdata’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    first, last

The following object is masked from ‘package:stats’:

    nobs

The following object is masked from ‘package:utils’:

    object.size

Help files with alias or concept or title matching ‘startsWith’ using
fuzzy matching:


dplyr::reexports        Objects exported from other packages
  Aliases: starts_with
gdata::startsWith       Determine if a character string "starts with"
                        with the specified characters.
  Aliases: startsWith
tidyselect::select_helpers
                        Select helpers
  Aliases: starts_with


Type '?PKG::FOO' to inspect entries 'PKG::FOO', or 'TYPE?PKG::FOO' for
entries like 'PKG::FOO-TYPE'.
```

Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this issue? (I already tried to remove and install the library again).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: (1) `startsWith` is also in base R, no need for `gdata`. I can see no difference in functionality, perhaps I missed something. (2) I don't get an error with your code, it (still) prints just `TRUE`. (3) I have a masking that you don't list: `'package:base': startsWith`; since that function was added in R-3.3.0, released in [April 2016](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/). If that's the case (and it might suggest that `gdata` should depend on a more recent version of R), might I suggest you update your R? There have been lots of changes since then.

Comment: On my machine the first test script runs without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. 
I have the latest version of gdata but my R version is the 3.2.2 (that has no function startsWith I think). I cannot update it to a newer version because the server administrator of my company said that it is the latest release he can install on centOS. Anyway I would think that if i can install the latest version of the library with my R version, I should still be able to use its functions, am I right?

Comment: ok maybe I found the issue... this is the current code for gdata::startsWith()
`function (str, pattern, trim = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE)
{
   if (trim)
       str <- trim(str)
   if (ignore.case) {
       str <- toupper(str)
       pattern <- toupper(pattern)
   }
   base::startsWith(str, pattern)
}`

So probably I need the R version that includes startsWith in its own functions.